# Assigning a value to bitfield with length 1

Tags: c++, c, binary, bit-fields

Suppose I have

```
struct A
{
    signed char a:1;
    unsigned char b:1;
};
```

If I have

```
A two, three;
two.a = 2; two.b = 2;
three.a = 3; three.b = 3;
```

`two` will contain `0`s in its fields, while `three` will contain `1`s. So, this makes me think, that assigning a number to a single-bit-field gets the least significant bit (`2` is `10` in binary and `3` is `11`).

So, my question is - is this correct and cross-platform? Or it depends on the machine, on the compiler, etc. Does the standard says anything about this, or it's completely implementation defined?

<sub>Note: The same result may be achieved by assigning `0` and `1`, instead of `2` and `3` respectively. I used `2` and `3` just for illustrating my question, I wouldn't use it in a real-world situation</sub>

<sub>P.S. And, yes, I'm interesting in both - `C` and `C++`, please don't tell me they are different languages, because I know this :)</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules in this case are no different than in case of full-width arithmetic. Bit-fields behave the same way as the corresponding full-size types, except that their width is limited by the value you specified in the bit-field declaration (6.7.2.1/9 in C99).

Assigning an overflowing value to a signed bit-field leads to implementation-defined behavior, which means that behavior you observe with bit-field `a` is generally not portable.

Assigning an overflowing value to an unsigned bit-field uses the rules of modulo arithmetic, meaning that the value is taken modulo `2^N`, where `N` is the width of the bit-field. This means, for example, that assigning even numbers to your bit-field `b` will always produce value `0`, while assigning odd numbers to such bit-field will always produce `1`.

Comment: So, you mean that if I set `A::b` with `2`, it will always be `0` and this does _not_ depend on the platform, on the binary representation (one/two complement), on the compiler at all and it's cross-platform? The same for `3` and value of the bit `1`.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: There are different flavors of overflow. Your quote applies to overflow that occurs during evaluation of arithmetic operators. Overflow that occurs during signed arithmetic *conversions* is described by 6.3.1.3 as "either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised".

Comment: @AndreyT: Not just arithmetic operators; all expressions. But, I agree 6.3.1.3 overrides that for conversions.